# Positive definiteness of a matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B \in \mathbb C^{n \times m}$. Prove that 
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}I & B \\ B^* & I \end{pmatrix}.$$ 
is positive definite iff spectral radius $\rho(B^*B) < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a result involving the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)
that implies that $A$ is positive definite if and only if both $I_n$ and $I_m - B^*B$ are positive definite. See Prop. 2.1 of [these notes](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/schur-comp.pdf), for example.

In turn, you can show $I_m - B^* B$ is positive definite if and only if $\rho(B^* B) < 1$.